# super() for multiple inheritance inconsistency

Tags: python, inheritance

I've two examples of multiple inheritance that's look like the same but I'm getting differents results order.

[First Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7416112) from [Joël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736151/joel):

```
class A(object):
    def t(self):
        print 'from A'

class B(object):
    def t(self):
        print 'from B'

class C(A): pass

class D(C, B): pass
```

And as a result we've:

```
>>> d = D()
>>> d.t() # Will print "from A"

>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, 
<class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Then in the [Second Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367) from [Callisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395354/callisto):

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "first"

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print "second"

class Third(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print "third"

class Fourth(Second, Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print "that's it"
```

And as a result we've:

```
>>> f = Fourth()
second
that's it

>>> Fourth.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Fourth'>, <class '__main__.Second'>, <class '__main__.Third'>
<class '__main__.First'>, <type 'object'>)
```

As you can see, the flow order of `MRO` are different, in the Second Example it don't reach `First` before `Third` but in the First Example it pass by `A` before going to `B`.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Eric: the question is: why in the Second Example it don't reach First before Third but in the First Example it pass by A before going to B?

Comment: @segfolt: Yes, If you follow the MRO you'll see that the behavior (order) are different but the code are equivalent, in my point of view the MRO ordem should be the same.

Comment: @RafaelCapucho: In what way is the code equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

There is no inconsistency. The MRO is based on the C3 algorithm which is explained by [Chaturvedi](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#computing-the-mro) and more formally by [Simionato](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

---

Regarding:

> in the Second Example it don't reach First before Third but in the
>   First Example it pass by A before going to B.

Since `Third` is defined by

```
class Third(First):
```

`Third` must show up before `First` in the MRO.

Chaturvedi explains this with the rule,

> If A is a superclass of B, then B has precedence over A. Or, B should
>   always appear before A in all `__mro__`s (that contain both).

While in the First example, the equivalent of `First` and `Third` is `A` and `C`. Since `C` is defined by

```
class C(A):
```

`C` comes before `A` in the MRO.

Why `A` comes before `B` is more complicated. It is ultimately due to `C` being listed before `B` in the bases of `D`. In Simionato's notation,

```
L[D] = L[D(C,B)] = D + merge(L[C], L[B], CB)
     = D + merge(CAO, BO, CB)
     = D + C + merge(AO, BO, B)
     = D + C + A + merge(O, BO, B)
     = D + C + A + B + merge(O, O)
     = D + C + A + B + O
```

and in the second example,

```
L[4] = L[4(2, 3)] = 4 + merge(L[2], L[3], 23)
     = 4 + merge(21O, 31O, 23)
     = 4 + 2 + merge(1O, 31O, 3)
     = 4 + 2 + 3 + merge(1O, 1O)    # Third must come before First
     = 4 + 2 + 3 + 1 + merge(O, O)
     = 4 + 2 + 3 + 1 + O
```

The [operative rule](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) being:

> take the head of the first list, i.e L[B1][0]; **if this head is not in the tail of any of the other lists**, then add it to the linearization
>   of C and remove it from the lists in the merge, otherwise look at the
>   head of the next list and take it, if it is a good head. Then repeat
>   the operation until all the class are removed or it is impossible to
>   find good heads. In this case, it is impossible to construct the
>   merge, Python 2.3 will refuse to create the class C and will raise an
>   exception.

(My emphasis explains why `Third` must come before `First`).

Comment: Then, In my second example, the order `4 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1` occurs because i reach the instruction right in the `2` classes, if there aren't one `__init__` instruction in the `2` so it'll try the classe `1` before backtracking to `4` right?

I guess that i got, they'll do somekind of left recursion until reach the instruction or the end and after that jump to right sibiling param.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having difficulty following what you are asking. I suggest reading [Chaturvedi](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html) to understand the flavor of the algorithm, and to read [Simionato](http://www.python.org/2.3/mro.html) for the details. Then refer the equations in my post where I show all the gory details for your two examples.

Comment: @unutbu: I'm reading the Simionato's tutorial. In the tutorial, I don't understand the transition:`A + B + merge(DEO,CDFO,C) = A + B + C + merge(DEO,DFO)`. In my opinion it should be `= A + B + D + merge(EO, CFO, C)` because of the operative rule. I'd be very thankful if you could explain the transition. thanks!

Comment: @segfolt: `D` shows up in the tail of `CDFO`, so `D` can not be used as the next class in the linearization. So the algorithm goes on to try the next head, which is `C`. `C` is not in the tail of any of the other lists in the mergo, so it is a "good head". `merge(DEO, CDFO, C) = C + merge(DEO, CFO, C)`.

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks a lot! I omitted that the tail is all the list excepted the head. I thought it was the last element of the list.

Comment: @unutbu: Btw: according to Simionato's tutorial, it should be `L[D(C,B)] = D + merge(L[C], L[B], CB)` rather than `L[D(C,B)] = D + merge(L[C], L[B], C, B)` in your post, no?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same, in the first example, all "dad" objects inherits object, as the D loads C  that loads A and, in the order of MRO, B (as invoked by D)

In second, ALL "dad" objects inherits the class First. At this time, Python load First in last as it's need to process Second and Third.

PS: It's my theory, but it's just logic.

Here is an running example of what you implemented in his examples: http://ideone.com/pfzXiG

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "first"

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print "second"

class Third(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print "third"

class Fourth(Second, Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print "that's it"

print "First: "
print Fourth.__mro__

class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "first"

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "second"

class Third(First):
    def __init__(self):
        print "third"

class Fourth(Third, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print "that's it"
print "Second:"
print Fourth.__mro__
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first inheritance heirarchy looks like this:

```
D
|\
C B
| |
A |
 \|
   object
```

Whereas your second is:

```
4
|\
2 3
 \|
  1
  |
  object
```

> why in the Second Example it don't reach `First` before `Third` but in the First Example it pass by `A` before going to `B`?

Why would you expect these to behave the same way? Looking at the graphs, the relationship between `A` and `B` is completely different to that between `First` and `Third`