# Trouble understanding super() when calling multiple parents

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, super

I've been doing research on Python 3 (my code sample uses 3.7.2) and how to properly use `super()` when a class inherits more than one class.

I've read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415974/better-way-to-access-super-class-method-in-multiple-inheritance), and this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) and this [article](https://realpython.com/python-super/). I think the problem is that the SO links are for an older version of Python, while the article is for Python 3, but it's still confusing.

Suppose I had the following code (don't worry if you think that the relationship can be modeled better, this is just an example to illustrate my problem):

```
class Weapon:

    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage

class Reloadable:

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

class Sniper(Weapon, Reloadable):

    def __init__(self, name, damage, amount, scope_type):
        super().__init__(name, damage)
        super().__init__(self, amount)
        self.scope_type = scope_type

    def adjust_scope(self):
        print("Adjusting my scope")
```

`Main:`

```
gun = Sniper("Standard Sniper", 10, 20, "small")
gun.adjust_scope()

print(Sniper.__mro__)
```

and the `MRO`:

```
(<class 'inheritnacewithsuper.Sniper'>, 
 <class 'inheritnacewithsuper.Weapon'>, 
 <class 'inheritnacewithsuper.Reloadable'>, <class 'object'>)
```

The code works and called the desired parent classes, but I want to make sure, when using Python 3.7, and `super()`, is doing `super().__init__(name, damage)` and `super().__init__(self, amount)`, the correct way to initialize the parent constructors?

The article doesn't do that, instead it called the `super()` for only one class (`RightPyramid(Square, Triangle)`).

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track, and using proper practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` requires your code *cooperates*. Your `Weapon` and `Reloadable` classes don't, so you actually *don't want to use `super()` here*. You'd call the unbound methods directly on those base classes:

```
class Sniper(Weapon, Reloadable):
    def __init__(self, name, damage, amount, scope_type):
        Weapon.__init__(self, name, damage)
        Reloadable.__init__(self, amount)
        self.scope_type = scope_type
```

Without `super()`, the `__init__` methods are unbound so you need to pass in `self` explicitly.

See [*super() considered super!*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by Python core developer Raymond Hettinger (or the [Python conference presentation of the same name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) for a great overview how to use `super()` in a cooperative manner.

To be fully cooperative, *all* classes in your hierarchy should pass on the `super().<methodname>()` calls in the chain of classes. With mix-in classes like `Reloadable`, you'd want to either use a base no-op class or handle errors when calling `super().__init__()`, or pass on arguments as keyword arguments, and have each `__init__()` method *accept* arbitrary keyword arguments to pass on again:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, damage, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        # pass on any remaining arguments
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Reloadable:    
    def __init__(self, amount, **kwargs):
        self.amount = amount
        # pass on any remaining arguments
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Sniper(Weapon, Reloadable):    
    def __init__(self, name, damage, amount, scope_type):
        self.scope_type = scope_type
        super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage, amount=amount)

    def adjust_scope(self):
        print("Adjusting my scope")
```

Comment: When you say don't cooperate, you mean using `ABC` module?

Comment: @EmilyScott: no, I mean that the base classes also use `super()` to pass on the call chain.

Comment: This is the second time where useful information was available at PyCon, and I feel like I'm missing out. This goes beyond the scope of the question, but when you can't attend, how do you keep up with that goes on at PyCon?

Comment: You see how you were able to do `super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage, amount=amount)`, with out calling `Reloadable` to pass in amount, where does it say you can do that in the blog post or presentation?

Comment: @EmilyScott: using keyword arguments makes the *the caller and callee need to have a matching argument signature* requirement much easier; the `**kwargs` catch-all makes each `__init__` implementation 'tolerant' of extra arguments being passed down the chain.

Comment: @EmilyScott: as Raymond writes: *A more flexible approach is to have every method in the ancestor tree cooperatively designed to accept keyword arguments and a keyword-arguments dictionary, to remove any arguments that it needs, and to forward the remaining arguments using `**kwds`, eventually leaving the dictionary empty for the final call in the chain.*

Comment: @EmilyScott: `Sniper()` here accepts `name`, `damage`, and `amount` as expliictly named arguments, so we need to pass those on to the base classes, and we do so here by passing them on as keyword arguments.

Comment: @EmilyScott: as for tracking PyCon: just about every talk is recorded and put on YouTube, often within hours of being recorded. Check the schedule for a given year, pick the talks that you think might be interesting, and look them up on YouTube. E.g. look at the [2018 schedule](https://us.pycon.org/2018/schedule/talks/), then plug in a title with 'pycon 2018' in to your favourite search engine and it'll lead you to the talk.

Comment: Huge thanks for the help and answers in the comments. Thanks for the schedule resource!

Comment: I asked a followup [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735138/when-using-the-abc-module-are-keyword-arguments-a-good-practice), but no one seems to want to answer. Maybe you can provide some insight.